# How to convert mzXML to mzML format (mass spectrometry files)?

Tags: python, linux

How to convert mzXML to mzML format (mass spectrometry files) preferably under Linux and/or Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ProteoWizard`](http://proteowizard.sourceforge.net/) offers this functionality:

```
msconvert your_mzXML_file --mzML
```

`FileConverter` of `OpenMS` (I believe using the integrated ProteoWizard) also does [this](https://abibuilder.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de/archive/openms/Documentation/release/latest/html/TOPP_FileConverter.html).