# How to extract date of acquisiton from mzXML and mzML files with Python?

Tags: python

I would like to extract date of acquisiton from mzXML and mzML files, using Python. Is it possible e.g. with [Pyteomics](https://pypi.org/project/pyteomics/)? pymzml is only for mzML files. Are there other libraries that can do that? I assume of course that the date of acquisition is recored in mzXML/mzML files.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) add small example input files (they need to be valid mzXML and mzML) and ii) the output you expect from that input so we can test any answers we come up with.

Comment: This question is really targeted at people who know what a mzXML or mzML file is and who use e.g. pyteomics. Also, I don't know how to attach a data file like this to a stackoverflow question. I think, only images can be uploaded. Thanks

Comment: You can simply paste a few lines into your question and then use the `{}` button to format as code. And it isn't a question of showing the format but of having clear input and output requirements so solutions can be tested.

Comment: I don't think that is necessary.

Comment: It isn't about necessary, it is about helping others help you. If you include a test file, then we can test our solutions and make sure they actually work. You have the option of making it harder for people to help you, so in that sense it isn't "necessary". But if you want to ask a good, well received question that doesn't get downvoted, then it is necessary. Your call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to extract anything from mzML and mzXML with Pyteomics. You will have to look at your files and figure out what you need to do, though, because you need to know what element contains the information that you want. I don't often work with mzXML and in the files that I have I do not see an acquisition date at all. With mzML it appears that the `<run>` element has this information:

```
<run id="small_raw" defaultInstrumentConfigurationRef="IC1" startTimeStamp="2005-07-20T14:44:22">
```

So I can get it like this:

```
In [1]: from pyteomics import mzml

In [2]: with mzml.MzML('tests/test.mzML') as f:
   ...:     print(next(f.iterfind('run', recursive=False))['startTimeStamp'])
   ...: 
2005-07-20T14:44:22
```

P.S. Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of Pyteomics.

Answer (score 0):

`pymzml` certainly works via [Bald *et al* 2012](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/28/7/1052/209917):

```
conda install -c bioconda pymzml
```

Whilst this only works with `mzML` you simply convert `mzXML` to `pymzml` via `ProteoWizard`

```
msconvert your_mzXML_file --mzML
```

[It is described here with your previous question with @haci](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/10807/how-to-convert-mzxml-to-mzml-format-mass-spectrometry-files)

I believe you managed this via

```
conda create -n openms -c bioconda openms
FileConverter -in file.mzXML -out file.mzML
```

I suspect the underlying question is direct parsing in `mzXML` without the need to perform a conversion from `mzXML` to `mzML` or without using `Bioconductor`

---

**Possibility** The following may be of use `massspec-toolbox` at:

http://code.google.com/p/massspec-toolbox/source/browse/#svn/trunk/mzxml

Note, I've not tested nor read this but the repository looks genuine.